# LinkedIn JavaScript SDK: logout fails with error message: Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

The [LinkedIn JavaScript SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk) provides an option to logout by calling `IN.User.logout();`

It used to work before, but now I get the below error message:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/connect/logout?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com%3A9080%2Ftest%2Fsecure%2Fweb%2Flinkedin.html&token=1laTMk0vaNkL7ixTVueGpt3aZZ94eVfnR-2-&isFramed=false&lang=en_US&oauth_token=&api_key=my-app-key&callback=%7BCALLBACK%7D&_ts=1504591845113.4253&xd_origin_host=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xxx.com%3A9080' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

The JS SDK seems to open a blank window to run a call to logout using
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/connect/logout?oauth_token={OAUTH_TOKEN}&api_key={API_KEY}&callback={CALLBACK}

Could anyone please tell me how can I make this work?

Example:

```
 <html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: my_api_key
    authorize: true
    scope: r_basicprofile
    r_emailaddress
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    //After successfully Login
    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    // Error in API call
    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    // Get the needed Data
    function getProfileData() {
        IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id,email-address,first-name,last-name,formatted-name)").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
    }

    // destroy the session of linkedin
    function closeSession() {
        IN.User.logout();
        return true;
    }

    function login() {
        IN.User.authorize(function () {
            getProfileData();
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="login()" value="Login"/>
<input type="button" onclick="closeSession()" value="Logout"/>

</html>
```